# NetLogo Turtles stuck in a line

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a model of tax evasion. I have a number of stationary turtles called traders, and moving turtles called customers. Each customers moves in the direction of the closest trader, but if more than 1 trader is nearby, the customer will move to the trader with the lowest price.

At random runs but not always, the customers line up and get stuck for some reason. It seems they get stuck more often the more complexities I add to the model, even though these additions have nothing to do with movement.

Here is the movement code

```
  ask customers[
set num-traders-close count traders with [distance myself < 10]  
set closest-trader distance min-one-of traders [distance myself]

to find_food
      ifelse ( num-traders-close < 2 ) ;;If only 0 or 1 traders within 10 spaces, move towards it. If number is 2 or larger, go towards cheaper resturant
  [nearest_food] 
  [choose-cheapest]
end


 to nearest_food
 let nearest-food min-one-of (traders )[distance myself]
     ifelse closest-trader > 1
     [face nearest-food
     fd 1]
     [move-to nearest-food ]
 end

 to choose-cheapest
   let cheapest-food min-one-of traders [price]
     ifelse closest-trader > 1
     [face cheapest-food
     fd 1]
     [move-to cheapest-food ]
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your code by adding my own setup and go function, 
but anyway if you set the number of traders and closest trader in every tick you will get lined up people in only one or two traders. Like following image:

### [image]

But if you set this on your setup function they will always go to the one they checked first, just like following image

[image]

But this way might not be reasonable, you might need to ask your customers to move around randomly too, so they can change these values later in go function.

in the code below they move around and they  update their num-near-traders and closet trader. There is no line up and I asked them to move around too, so it's more reasonable, but I am not sure about your requirements.

```
Breed [Customers Customer]
Breed [Traders trader]
Customers-own 
[num-traders-close closest-trader]
  traders-own [price]

to setup 
  random-seed 234523432
  clear-all
  Create-traders 10 [move-to one-of patches set price random 100 set shape "house" set color white]
  create-Customers 50 [move-to one-of patches set shape "person" ]


  reset-ticks
end


to go
  ask customers
  [
    set-customers
    find_food
    ]
  tick
end
to set-customers
  rt random 100
  fd 0.5
set num-traders-close count traders with [distance myself < 5]  
set closest-trader distance min-one-of traders [distance myself]
 end
to find_food
      ifelse ( num-traders-close < 2 ) ;;If only 0 or 1 traders within 10 spaces, move towards it. If number is 2 or larger, go towards cheaper restaurant
  [nearest_food] 
  [choose-cheapest]
end
```

Comment: I tried implementing your code, but to no avail. They now form larger clusters of jaggering and stuck customers, instead of lines. However, if I have a low number of traders and customers, both codes work. But as I increase the number, they get stuck a lot of the time

Comment: for  [nearest_food] and [choose-cheapest] use your own code , I tried it with higher number of traders after 500 ticks almost 80% of customers choose same trader which is not the cheapest one but its closet one, the problem is not the code, it is the logic behind the code

Comment: However, you responded to an earlier code where I ended up with a similar problem, and that solved my problem!